# Instantiate one object for all blazor pages in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor webassmbly app and I want to instantiate an object only once that can be shared between all the blazor pages on client side. What I want to do is to instantiate this object when the application starts, in `Program.cs` and then inject that object in all pages to use it. What I did was to create this class :

```
  public class AccountService
  {
        HttpCaller _httpCaller;
        AuthenticationStateProvider _provider;
        public AccountViewModel _currentAccount;

        public AccountService(HttpCaller caller, AuthenticationStateProvider provider)
        {
            _httpCaller = caller;
            _provider = provider;
        }

        public async Task<OperationResult<AccountViewModel>> GetCurrentAccount()
        {
            if (await UserIsAuthenticated())
            {
                return await _httpCaller.HttpCall<bool, AccountViewModel>(API.GetCurrentAccount, true, true);                            
            }

            return NotAuthenticated<AccountViewModel>();
        }

  }
```

I call `GetCurrentAccount()` method and associate the result to `_currentAccount` property in in `Program.cs` class :

```
 AccountService accountService =  serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AccountService>();
 var result = await accountService.GetCurrentAccount();
 if (result.IsSucces)
 {
    accountService._currentAccount = result.Result;
 };
```

Then I inject `AccountService` object in a blazor page and my expectation is that `_currentAccount` property should contain the `AccountViewModel` object associated in `Program.cs`. But is `null`. The `AccountService` object is created as a scoped object before calling `GetCurrentMethod()` in `Program.cs` class:

```
  builder.Services.AddScoped<AccountService>();
```

From my knowledge a scoped object should exist until the app is reloaded, there is no reloading but the `_currentAccount` property is still `null`.

Comment: It's not clear where your `serviceProvider` comes from, and that probably is where the problem is.

Comment: I simply instantiate the service provider in Program.cs file like this: ServiceProvider serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I simply instantiate the service provider in Program.cs file like this:
> `ServiceProvider serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();`

Try it like this:

```
var app = appBuilder.Build();

AccountService accountService =  app.Services.GetRequiredService<AccountService>();
 
... // do your thing here

await app.Run();
```

That way you use the *same* Service provider as later on in your program.

Comment: It worked, but I don't uderstand exactly why. I was building 2 different service providers ?

Comment: Yes, BuildServiceProvider() gets you a new instance, with its own top-level scope. When you had traced the constructor of AccountService you should have seen 2 instances.